# Using only omniauth (twitter) sign-in with Devise, Rails 3, Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, devise, omniauth

I have a setup based on Railscasts 209, 210, 235 and 236 - Twitter sign-in is working great; however I would like to entirely remove the ability for users to create accounts local to my app.  In other words, if you want to sign in, you need to use your Twitter acct.  I'd just as soon not bother managing local accounts (for now - may add it back in at some point).

I can't really find any solid pointers to how to do this, and playing around with the Devise routes and such haven't yielded very good results.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this one from railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth

Comment: Oh hey.  How about that.  I didn't even consider that using Devise isn't really buying me anything if I'm not using anything other than Omniauth - thanks - still would be interesting to know how to turn all the local account stuff off in Devise (is it as simple as killing database_authenticatable in the User model?)

Comment: Kind of solved this; nasty hack but it works (for now); added this to my routes:

    devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"} do
      get "/users/sign_up" => "authentications#index"
      get "/users/sign_in" => "authentications#index"
    end

Basically hijacks the Devise forms and sends them directly to the authentications controller, as described in the Railscasts I mentioned...

Comment: just search "Using OmniAuth without other authentications" in devise official wiki https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: @cyrusd - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> Kind of solved this; nasty hack but it works (for now); added this to
>   my routes:
>
> ```
> devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"} do
>   get "/users/sign_up" => "authentications#index"
>   get "/users/sign_in" => "authentications#index"
> end
> ```
>
> Basically hijacks the Devise forms and sends them directly to the
>   authentications controller, as described in the Railscasts I
>   mentioned...

~ answer per [cyrusd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1161155/cyrusd)